# Creation of a Serverless Discord Bot with AWS CDK in Typescript

Tags: typescript, discord, aws-cdk, aws-serverless

I'm try to create a serverless discord bot on AWS using typescript.

I've seen a lot of tutorial :

- [Building a Serverless Discord Bot on AWS](https://gemisis.medium.com/building-a-serverless-discord-bot-on-aws-5dc7d972c9c6)
- [Serverless Discord Custom Slash Commands bot with AWS API Gateway and Lambda](https://oozio.medium.com/serverless-discord-bot-55f95f26f743)

But I don't really understand how we add slash commands for the bot. I've search on some git project:

- [Bot in python](https://github.com/oozio/discord_aws_bot_demo)
- [Bot in JS but using AWS SAM](https://github.com/ytausch/serverless-discord-bot)

I have made the API Gateway endpoint and linked it to my discord bot, also have linked my Lambda function to API Gateway endpoint.

My problem is how to create slash commands for my Discord bot (in TypeScript) and I did'nt find any information about it.

Comment: Are you using the Discord.JS library (as you've tagged) or handling raw API requests (as you're describing)?

Comment: For the moment, I don't use Discord.JS library, I'm only trying to make communicate Discord bot with AWS API Gateway for adding slash command.

Comment: discord.js tag description: "Use this tag for questions about the usage of discord.js, not for questions regarding the Discord API or Discord in general (for API questions, use the 'discord' tag)"

Comment: Oops, sorry, I update tags

Comment: its also not really much of a aws-cdk question ;) your question is how to make use of the discord api to recognize slash commands coming from a webhook. CDK would help you set up the resources in AWS, but wont do anything for your slash commands.

Your best bet is to study up on the https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands documentation. In short, you are going to use the webhooks on your discord server to send Discord API contract commands to an API Gateway endpoint to be processed by lambdas.